# Proving that if U $\vdash$ A, then $U \cup {B} \vdash A$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove the above. I understand that if A is a logical consequence of a set of premises, ie if whenever every element in U is true so is A, then adding another element B shouldn’t change A’s truth value if all other elements of U remain true. However, I am struggling to formalize this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A purely syntactic proof of this would involve induction on proofs. For a semantic proof, you could note that $\models$ and $\vdash$ are equivalent and prove that if $U \models A$, then $U \cup B \models A$.

Answer (score 0):

$1.\ U\\2.\ U\vdash A\\3.\ A\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(1,2)}\\4.\ B\vdash A\qquad\qquad\text{(3)}\\ 5.\ U\lor B\vdash A\qquad\text{(2,4)}$